# Cannot execute database statement from another php file using include

Tags: php

What I'm doing wrong after adding class define to StoreUser.php file and calling it from  store.php file because it doesn't work any moore? It worked fine inside file StoreUser.php without class define and function see below.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "riskinarviointilomake";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
//private $email;

if(isset($_GET["email"])){

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if (!( $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id,email,
  encrypted_password) VALUES(?,?,?)"))){

    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $unique_id,$email,$password);

    $unique_id=123457764;
    $password="df12467hh";  

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();


   }




  ?>
```

This doesn't work

```
class StoreUser{

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "riskinarviointilomake";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
//private $email;


public function store($email){
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if (!( $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id,email, encrypted_password) VALUES(?,?,?)"))){

    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $unique_id,$email,$password);

    $unique_id=123457764;
    $password="df12467hh";  

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();


 }
```

}

```
    <?php

    include 'StoreTest.php';

   if(isset($_GET['email'])){
     $email = $_GET['email'];
     $store = new StoreTest();
     $store->store($email);


   }


 ?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Nothing. There is no any added rows in MySQL database table when I use second case. First case can add rows. It is little bit difficult because this linuxMint is installed  (Lamp) not give any error. I got error via android volley but it was too cryptic find out problem. That is reason why I try find out problem only on php code by simple example.

Comment: I found php.ini settings. I modified it to show errors.  Now I get error message from php. There was syntax and non-object problems.